# Can't access with public IP address

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, nginx

I'm trying to run my own instance of a bitwarden vault on my Raspberry Pi. Everything works well. I can access it from my local network. Yet I can't access it outside of it with my public IP even though I forwarded my port and I check they were open with nmap.

I forwarded the 443 port. And I access it this way:

https://public.ip:443

So I have a forwarded port, a server running that runs perfectly on my local network. But still can't access it from any network.

Does anyone have a clue on why that doesn't work ?

Comment: Just an FYI, but `https://` implies port 443 (so `https://public.ip` should work without the extra `:443`). Regarding access, it might be worth including what the exact error you are recieving is.

Comment: I don't know where to look for errors, since my server is up and running. And the port is open. My browser says the answer is too slow.